# "Поделиться" в ВК без дополнительных окон

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Есть ли способ, зная логин и пароль пользователя отправить некий волшебный запрос, чтоб получить результат обычного нажатия кнопки "поделиться"?

ВК при нажатии на кнопку создаёт новое окно с авторизацией или с подтверждением шаринга (если авторизован), но в моём случае из-за ограничений среды может быть только одно открытое окно с одной страницей.

Вариант с `iframe` также не подходит.

Есть идеи? Или доказательство невозможности сабжа?

Comment: просто интересно: как вы узнаете и как храните логины и пароли пользователей от контакта?

Comment: В свои нарисованные поля попрошу ввести логин-пароль. Хранить пока не планируется. А если нужно будет, то добавим галочку для запоминания. Доступ к файловой системе там есть.

Answer (score 1):

На php curlом например можно... в чем проблема?
Нажимаешь на кнопку, оно загружает некую страницу, логинится в контакт, ну а потом почитать апи контакта и использовать, к примеру,

> **Для сайтов без поддержки JavaScript** Если Вы не можете
> выполнять JavaScript-сценарии на Вашем
> сайте, например Ваша блог-платформа не
> поддерживает этой функциональности, Вы
> можете размещать прямую ссылку для
> публикации ВКонтакте. Эта ссылка имеет
> следующий вид: 
> http://vkontakte.ru/share.php?url={адрес
> страницы}
>
> Код для ее размещения может выглядеть
> так:

```
<a href="http://vkontakte.ru/share.php?url=http://mysite.com" target="_blank">Поделиться ВКонтакте</a>
```

Comment: При чем тут пхп? У меня есть только одно html окно. Нет сервера. Нельзя открывать других окон. Можно посылать всяческие аякс запросы.

Comment: @cranx Тем более вам проще! Посылаете GET-запрос, получаете в качестве ответа DOM. Используете конструкции типа "form.submit" и пр. и радуетесь жизни

Comment: @stck Отличная идея, но я не могу получить DOM страницы с другого домена. Врядли ВК согласится для меня настроить кросс-доменную политику.